# Print driver for Epson Workforce Pro WP-4025

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

Does anybody run `Epson Workforce Pro WP-4025DW` on Ubuntu successfully?
If yes, which driver is similar.
For me it's not necessary to use all features, but I've no clue how different Epson printers are. Seems like it's not PostScript.

BTW: If there exists a driver for MacOS, is there something like a wrapper for Linux? (Sorry for this dumb question, better forget it.)

Comment: you may find this useful: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WP-4025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WP-4025 where they have a driver for your model for both 32 and 64 bit. Drivers for other Epson models are also available from here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX